# Powermock - java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to transform class

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermock

**Description:**

I am trying to test a static method from a class. I am using powerMock (1.6.2) + mockito (1.10.19) for mocking along with Junit4 (4.12) & java8.

**Issue:**

Getting the error: "Failed to transform class with name com.gs.ops.domain.StaticClass Reason: java.io.IOException: invalid constant type: 18"

**Solutions Tried:**

1. Googled threads for issue on with powermock - mockito & java-8
2. Excluded java assist from powermock and added java assist 3.19.0-GA
3. Tried different versions of powermock (1.5.4, 1.6.2...)

**Below is the exception stack trace:**

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to transform class with name com.StaticClass. Reason: java.io.IOException: invalid constant type: 18
        at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadMockClass(MockClassLoader.java:266)
        at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadModifiedClass(MockClassLoader.java:180)
        at org.powermock.core.classloader.DeferSupportingClassLoader.loadClass(DeferSupportingClassLoader.java:68)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:340)
        at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.createDelegatorFromClassloader(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:145)
        at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.createDelegatorFromClassloader(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:40)
        at org.powermock.tests.utils.impl.AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.createTestDelegators(AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:244)
        at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.<init>(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:61)
        at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.<init>(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:32)
        at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.<init>(PowerMockRunner.java:34)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
        at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104)
        at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
        at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
        at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
        at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
        at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:33)
        at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:67)
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: invalid constant type: 18
        at javassist.CtClassType.getClassFile2(CtClassType.java:203)
        at javassist.compiler.MemberResolver.lookupMethod(MemberResolver.java:110)
        at javassist.compiler.MemberResolver.lookupMethod(MemberResolver.java:96)
        at javassist.compiler.TypeChecker.atMethodCallCore(TypeChecker.java:704)
        at javassist.expr.NewExpr$ProceedForNew.setReturnType(NewExpr.java:243)
        at javassist.compiler.JvstTypeChecker.atCallExpr(JvstTypeChecker.java:146)
        at javassist.compiler.ast.CallExpr.accept(CallExpr.java:45)
        at javassist.compiler.TypeChecker.atVariableAssign(TypeChecker.java:248)
        at javassist.compiler.TypeChecker.atAssignExpr(TypeChecker.java:217)
        at javassist.compiler.ast.AssignExpr.accept(AssignExpr.java:38)
        at javassist.compiler.CodeGen.doTypeCheck(CodeGen.java:241)
        at javassist.compiler.CodeGen.atStmnt(CodeGen.java:329)
        at javassist.compiler.ast.Stmnt.accept(Stmnt.java:49)
        at javassist.compiler.CodeGen.atStmnt(CodeGen.java:350)
        at javassist.compiler.ast.Stmnt.accept(Stmnt.java:49)
        at javassist.compiler.CodeGen.atIfStmnt(CodeGen.java:404)
        at javassist.compiler.CodeGen.atStmnt(CodeGen.java:354)
        at javassist.compiler.ast.Stmnt.accept(Stmnt.java:49)
        at javassist.compiler.Javac.compileStmnt(Javac.java:568)
        at javassist.expr.NewExpr.replace(NewExpr.java:206)
        at org.powermock.core.transformers.impl.MainMockTransformer$PowerMockExpressionEditor.edit(MainMockTransformer.java:418)
        at javassist.expr.ExprEditor.loopBody(ExprEditor.java:211)
        at javassist.expr.ExprEditor.doit(ExprEditor.java:90)
        at javassist.CtClassType.instrument(CtClassType.java:1374)
        at org.powermock.core.transformers.impl.MainMockTransformer.transform(MainMockTransformer.java:74)
        at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadMockClass(MockClassLoader.java:251)
        ... 24 more
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: invalid constant type: 18
        at javassist.bytecode.ConstPool.readOne(ConstPool.java:1090)
        at javassist.bytecode.ConstPool.read(ConstPool.java:1033)
        at javassist.bytecode.ConstPool.<init>(ConstPool.java:149)
        at javassist.bytecode.ClassFile.read(ClassFile.java:737)
        at javassist.bytecode.ClassFile.<init>(ClassFile.java:108)
        at javassist.CtClassType.getClassFile2(CtClassType.java:190)
        ... 49 more
```

**Pom file:**

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
                    <artifactId>powermock-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
                    <artifactId>powermock-reflect</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.19.0-GA</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 40):

Powermock 1.6.3 uses javassist 3.15.2-GA which does not support certain types. Using 3.18.2-GA javassist worked for me. You may want to override dependency in your project.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        <version>3.18.2-GA</version>
    </dependency>
```

You may face another problem for which the solution lies here [Mockito + PowerMock LinkageError while mocking system class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16520699/mockito-powermock-linkageerror-while-mocking-system-class/21268013#21268013)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 14):

So there seems to be issue with `javassist` (bytecode toolkit) prior to `3.18.2`, as there's a resolved [JIRA ticket-223](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JASSIST-223?_sscc=t).

**1 -** To find javassist version in your pom.xml, can use `mvn dependency` task

```
$ mvn dependency:tree | grep javassist
[INFO] |     \- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.14.0-GA:compile
```

which is used by the `powermock-module-junit4-rule` ,

```
[INFO] +- org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4-rule:jar:1.4.9:test
[INFO] |  +- org.powermock:powermock-classloading-base:jar:1.4.9:test
[INFO] |  \- org.powermock:powermock-core:jar:1.4.9:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.14.0-GA:compile
```

**2 -** So, updating the `javassist` version by explicitly to any versions `>= 3.18.2` should work.

As, in my case, I am using use `3.20.0-GA`

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        <version>3.20.0-GA</version>
    </dependency>
```

*Working eg. with `scalatest`*

```
@PowerMockIgnore(Array("javax.management.*"))
@RunWith(classOf[PowerMockRunner])
@PrepareForTest(Array(classOf[Configurator]))
class LogServiceSpec {

  @Test
  def initialises_log4j2_on_each_instance_call() {
    PowerMockito.mockStatic(classOf[Configurator])

    val logService1 = new LogService
    PowerMockito.verifyStatic(Mockito.times(1))
    Configurator.initialize(Matchers.anyString(), Matchers.eq("log4j.config"))
  }
}
```

Comment: Would you mind helping me here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72532927/caused-by-java-lang-runtimeexception-java-io-ioexception-invalid-constant-typ? I updated dependency, no help

Answer (score 6):

This is caused because of the conflict of dependencies. Resolving the dependency conflicts is one way to resolve this issue and the other way is to reorder `<dependency></dependency>` elements in your pom.xml. Move the powermock dependency declarations to the top of the `<dependencies></dependencies>` section. This is a complete hack and the right way to resolve it would be to resolve the dependency conflicts.

To identify those conflict you may use the command "mvn dependency:tree". Here is the dependency tree for my application for which I came across this same problem. Notice that there are two dependencies of "javassist" in the tree.

```
[INFO] +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:1.10.19:test
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:jar:1.6.4:test
[INFO] |  \- org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4-common:jar:1.6.4:test
[INFO] |     +- org.powermock:powermock-core:jar:1.6.4:compile
[INFO] |     <span style="background-color: #FFFF00">|  \- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.20.0-GA:compile</span>
[INFO] |     \- org.powermock:powermock-reflect:jar:1.6.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:jar:1.6.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.powermock:powermock-api-support:jar:1.6.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.7.14:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.14:compile
[INFO] |  \- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.struts:struts2-core:jar:2.3.16.3-atlassian-6:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- ognl:ognl:jar:3.0.6:provided
<span style="background-color: #FFFF00">
[INFO] |  |     \- javassist:javassist:jar:3.11.0.GA:provided</span>
[INFO] |  +- com.atlassian:webwork-compat:jar:1.24:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.freemarker:freemarker:jar:2.3.16-atlassian-34:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- logkit:logkit:jar:1.2:provided
[INFO] |  +- opensymphony:sitemesh:jar:2.5-atlassian-6:provided
[INFO] |  +- commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:jar:1.3.1:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.tuckey:urlrewritefilter:jar:4.0.3:provided
[INFO] |  +- velocity-tools:velocity-tools:jar:1.2:provided
[INFO] |  +- commons-dbutils:commons-dbutils:jar:1.3:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:jar:1.3:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.atlassian.bamboo:atlassian-user-crowd-provider:jar:5.10.0:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- com.atlassian.crowd:crowd-integration-client-rest:jar:2.7.2:provided
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.atlassian.crowd:crowd-integration-client-common:jar:2.7.2:provided
[INFO] |  |  |     \- com.atlassian.security:atlassian-cookie-tools:jar:3.2:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- com.atlassian.crowd:crowd-integration-api:jar:2.7.2:provided
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.atlassian.crowd:embedded-crowd-api:jar:2.7.2:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- com.atlassian.user:atlassian-user-api:jar:4.1.1:provided
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.opensymphony.propertyset:api:jar:1.6.0-m1:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- com.atlassian.user:atlassian-user-ldap:jar:4.1.1:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- org.acegisecurity:acegi-security:jar:1.0.4:provided
[INFO] |  |  |  \- oro:oro:jar:2.0.8:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- com.atlassian.crowd:crowd-integration-seraph25:jar:2.7.2:provided
[INFO] |  +- javax.xml.stream:stax-api:jar:1.0-2:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.atlassian.core:atlassian-core:jar:5.0.2:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- com.atlassian.image:atlassian-image-consumer:jar:1.0.1:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-embedder:jar:3.0.4:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-settings:jar:3.0.4:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:3.0.4:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-model-builder:jar:3.0.4:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-compat:jar:3.0.4:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-classworlds:jar:2.4:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-inject-plexus:jar:2.3.0:provided
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-inject-bean:jar:2.3.0:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-component-annotations:jar:1.5.5:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-sec-dispatcher:jar:1.3:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-cipher:jar:1.7:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- commons-cli:commons-cli:jar:1.2:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:3.0.4:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.octo.captcha:jcaptcha:jar:2.0-alpha-1:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.octo.captcha:jcaptcha-api:jar:2.0-alpha-1:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.jhlabs:filters:jar:2.0.235:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.struts:struts2-sitemesh-plugin:jar:2.1.8.1:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.10:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.atlassian.plugins:atlassian-plugins-schema:jar:4.0.5:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- com.atlassian.plugins:atlassian-plugins-osgi:jar:4.0.5:provided
[INFO] |  |     +- com.atlassian.plugins:atlassian-plugins-osgi-events:jar:4.0.5:provided
[INFO] |  |     +- biz.aQute.bnd:biz.aQute.bndlib:jar:2.4.1:provided
[INFO] |  |     +- org.apache.felix:org.apache.felix.framework:jar:4.2.1:provided
[INFO] |  |     \- org.twdata.pkgscanner:package-scanner:jar:0.9.5:provided
[INFO] |  \- xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.11.0:provided
[INFO] |     \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.4.01:provided
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.12:test
[INFO] +- info.cukes:cucumber-java:jar:1.2.4:test
[INFO] |  \- info.cukes:cucumber-core:jar:1.2.4:test
[INFO] |     +- info.cukes:cucumber-html:jar:0.2.3:test
[INFO] |     +- info.cukes:cucumber-jvm-deps:jar:1.0.5:test
[INFO] |     \- info.cukes:gherkin:jar:2.12.2:test
[INFO] +- info.cukes:cucumber-junit:jar:1.2.4:test
[INFO] +- com.atlassian.plugins:atlassian-plugins-osgi-testrunner:jar:1.2.3:test
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.wink:wink-client:jar:1.1.3-incubating:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.wink:wink-common:jar:1.1.3-incubating:test
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-annotation_1.1_spec:jar:1.0:test
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.2:test
[INFO] |  |  \- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.2.1.1:test
[INFO] |  +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:1.4:provided
[INFO] |  \- com.atlassian.upm:upm-api:jar:2.15:test
[INFO] +- javax.ws.rs:jsr311-api:jar:1.1.1:provided
[INFO] +- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.2.2-atlassian-1:compile
[INFO] +- com.mashape.unirest:unirest-java:jar:1.3.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.6:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpasyncclient:jar:4.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore-nio:jar:4.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:jar:4.3.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.json:json:jar:20090211:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.3.3:compile
[INFO] \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.3.3:compile
[INFO]    \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.3.0:compile
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, a "java.io.IOException: invalid constant type: 18" was caused by multiple versions of javassist libraries in my classpath - both 3.12.1.GA and 3.18.2-GA. The problem disappeared when i removed the older one.

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer! I got a similar error when running a Maven build with JDK8 and generating Java6 byte code. My pom looks like this:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <compilerVersion>1.6</compilerVersion>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
                <maxmem>2000m</maxmem>
                <fork>true</fork>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

When I reverted to JDK6 I no longer got the error.

Answer (score 0):

In my case JRE System Library --> Execution Environment was set up on JavaSE-1.7, but the only installed JRE was JRE1.8. So it was pointing to java 8 in place of java 7. Once I moved to java 7 it start working fine for me.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This issue is related to a compatibility issue with Java 8. could you execute your tests on java 7 ?

Answer (score 0):

Run "mvn dependency:tree | grep javassist" on terminal. If javaassist dependency is being shown in non test and test libraries. Now you only have to exclude it during runtime for tests. So the way to do this is adding a build plugin on the lines of:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
            <configuration>
                <classpathDependencyExcludes>
                    <classpathDependencyExcludes>javassist:javassist</classpathDependencyExcludes>
                </classpathDependencyExcludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

Please note the classpathDependencyExcludes might change for you based on your javassist version.