# Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: invalid constant type: 18

Tags: java, junit, powermock, powermockito, javassist

I am migrating old legacy app from Log4j1.x to 2.x and getting below error while running the test cases. I already went through link: [Powermock - java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to transform class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32854688/powermock-java-lang-illegalstateexception-failed-to-transform-class), but no lick

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to transform class with name com.ABCTest. Reason: java.io.IOException: invalid constant type: 18
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadMockClass(MockClassLoader.java:283)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadModifiedClass(MockClassLoader.java:192)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.DeferSupportingClassLoader.loadClass(DeferSupportingClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.createDelegatorFromClassloader(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:161)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.createDelegatorFromClassloader(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:48)
    at org.powermock.tests.utils.impl.AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.createTestDelegators(AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:113)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.<init>(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:71)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.<init>(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:32)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.<init>(PowerMockRunner.java:34)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:31)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:24)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:57)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:29)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:57)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:24)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createUnfilteredTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:76)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:526)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:770)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: invalid constant type: 18
    at javassist.CtClassType.getClassFile2(CtClassType.java:207)
    at javassist.CtClassType.getModifiers(CtClassType.java:370)
    at javassist.CtClassType.isInterface(CtClassType.java:358)
    at org.powermock.core.transformers.impl.ClassMockTransformer.transformMockClass(ClassMockTransformer.java:39)
    at org.powermock.core.transformers.impl.AbstractMainMockTransformer.transform(AbstractMainMockTransformer.java:247)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadMockClass(MockClassLoader.java:264)
    ... 28 more
```

Below is the maven dependency tree:

```
[INFO] +- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:3.5.1:test
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.8.2:test
[INFO] +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:1.10.19:test
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.1:test
[INFO] |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.1:test
[INFO] +- org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:jar:1.6.5:test
[INFO] |  \- org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4-common:jar:1.6.5:test
[INFO] |     +- org.powermock:powermock-core:jar:1.6.5:test
[INFO] |     |  \- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.20.0-GA:test
[INFO] |     \- org.powermock:powermock-reflect:jar:1.6.5:test
[INFO] +- org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:jar:1.6.5:test
[INFO] |  \- org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito-common:jar:1.6.5:test
[INFO] |     \- org.powermock:powermock-api-support:jar:1.6.5:test
[INFO] +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.4:compile
[INFO] +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.6:compile
[INFO] +- org.mybatis:mybatis-spring:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.mybatis:mybatis:jar:3.5.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.sybase:jconnect:jar:7.0.7:compile
[INFO] +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO] +- jdbc:jcon3:jar:0:compile
[INFO] +- commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-pool:commons-pool:jar:1.5.4:compile
[INFO] +- javax.jms:jms:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] +- javax.mail:mail:jar:1.4.5:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.5.6:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.5.6:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:3.2.9.RELEASE:test
[INFO] +- com.ubs.gfs.sbl.halo:HaloAxisWSClient:jar:29.3.1:compile
[INFO] +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] +- com.ibm.mq:com.ibm.mq.allclient:jar:9.1.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:jar:1.60:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:jar:1.60:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.jms:javax.jms-api:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.ibm.mq:connector:jar:7.0.1.8:compile
[INFO] +- axis:axis:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.axis:axis-jaxrpc:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.axis:axis-saaj:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-discovery:commons-discovery:jar:0.2:runtime
[INFO] +- wsdl4j:wsdl4j:jar:1.6.2:compile
[INFO] +- com.oracle:ojdbc6:jar:12.1.0.2:compile
[INFO] \- org.apache.poi:poi:jar:3.0.2-FINAL:compile
```

Note: even after updating the javassist library things did not worked for me

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
    <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
    <version>3.18.2-GA</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Does upgrading Javassist help?  That version is from seven years ago, and may not be able to handle CONSTANT_InvokeDynamic (18)   classes.

Comment: Unfortunately no, I tried to update to the latest version of javassist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused because of the conflict of dependencies. Resolving the dependency conflicts is one way to resolve this issue and the other way is to reorder `<dependency></dependency>` elements in your pom.xml. Move the powermock dependency declarations to the top of the `<dependencies></dependencies>` section. This is a complete hack and the right way to resolve it would be to resolve the dependency conflicts.

To identify those conflict you may use the command `"mvn dependency:tree"`. Here is the dependency tree for my application for which I came across this same problem. Notice that there are two dependencies of "javassist" in the tree.

**In my case, I am adding so many maven modules/components into my project, I added that dependency below the powermock dependency that start working the things.**