# Junit fails to run with java.lang.LinkageError duplicate class definition for name with log4j classes

Tags: java, junit, log4j, powermock, powermockito

When I run my unit tests, I get complaints from the test run phase of my build that there's a duplicate class in my classpath. I did not recently change my dependencies, so this is surprising.

> [junit] Exception in thread "Thread-4" java.lang.LinkageError: loader
> (instance of  org/powermock/core/classloader/MockClassLoader):
> attempted  duplicate class definition for name:
> "org/apache/log4j/pattern/Log4j1MdcPatternConverter"

The class in question changes when I try using the `@PowerMockIgnore` annotation to exclude that pattern, for example, if I do this:

```
@PowerMockIgnore({"org.apache.log4j.pattern.Log4j1MdcPatternConverter"})
```

It just complains about another class that's duplicated like Log4j1XmlLayout or Log4j1NdcPatternConverter. I can probably brute force which ones to exclude, but has anyone seen this problem before who knows the exclude pattern to use? The format I'd use is similar to [this question about LinkageErrors in unit tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16520699/mockito-powermock-linkageerror-while-mocking-system-class/38533182#38533182) but for different classes.

Some other questions and answers have mentioned that they changed the order for their dependencies with log4j and other Apache related packages; in this situation I cannot change the load order of the dependencies because I don't control them in the build environment (I.E. I cannot change something in Maven or Gradle). I'm looking for the smallest change possible, and that should be just placing a PowerMockIgnore annotation at the top of the test class that's failing.

Answer (score 0):

After lots of brute force, this is the pattern that makes the test run without duplicate class complaints (put this at the top of your class)

```
@PowerMockIgnore({
    "org.apache.log4j.pattern.Log4j1MdcPatternConverter",
    "org.apache.log4j.pattern.Log4j1NdcPatternConverter",
    "org.apache.log4j.layout.Log4j1XmlLayout",
    "org.apache.logging.log4j.*",
    "org.apache.logging.log4j.core.*"
})
```

Note the individual classes that had to be excluded, no wildcards, to get it to load and run.